# Two Ubuntu installs on one hard drive

Tags: linux, ubuntu, multi-boot, grub2, xubuntu

I am trying to install two different versions of Xubuntu (16.10 and 14.04.5 LTS) on the same machine but Grub is not showing the other Xubuntu as an option in the menu. The main reason for this is I need to use PHP 5.9 for work but personal projects I use PHP 7.
I'm not sure if it matters but both the installs are using crypt-luks and I tried creating a separate boot for each as well as them sharing the same boot partition (same result). Sadly this machine (XPS 15) only has room for one PCI SSD. I also have secure boot off and UEFI on.

**From what I can gather**

I'm no Ubuntu expert but I have been using it for a couple of years in typical Dual OS (single Ubuntu). What I think is happening is that *os-prober* is only detecting Windows (when I run update-grub)

```
#os-prober 
/dev/sda2@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi:Windows Boot Manager:Windows:efi
```

**Other Solutions**
I am also interested in any other ideas. I don't really want to use virtual box if I can help it (been there before). Docker is another option but getting the editor (Netbeans) CLI QA tools working from the container probably wont work. The other thing I could do is have a second OS running off a USB but that would be a last resort (I would prefer no cables).

Comment: I'd rather use a virtual machine. -- It would certainly be wise to try to install dual boot from the later version; the older one may not regognise the newer installation.

Answer (score 0):

It would be quite hard to debug your dual (triple?) boot issue without more information. Even so, it seems like it would be a large overhead to have to switch OS's just to change php versions.

So, as you are open to other solutions I can give you one which I make use of quite a lot these days. Note that I am not a php developer, but this should work just the same as other languages.

## The Nix Package Manager

Currently when I need to have multiple versions of some language/tool installed I use [nix](https://nixos.org/nix/).

Nix is a powerful package manager, I won't go into too much depth here, just know that it allows you to easily and safely use multiple versions of libraries/tools etc...  You can install it by running:

```bash
$ curl https://nixos.org/nix/install | sh
```

Generally curling a script to the shell is not a good idea, you can review the script and then manually download and launch it by going to https://nixos.org/nix/install.

Once installed, there are two quick ways to get started.

### List Versions

First, lets see what versions are available:

```
$ nix-env --query --available --attr-path php
nixpkgs.php56  php-5.6.29
nixpkgs.php    php-7-0.14
nixpkgs.php71  php-7.1.0
```

This command lists all the `php` versions currently available (note: this searches the default nixpkgs `channel` which you get after installing, I wont go into details here on what a nixpkgs `channel` is, just think of it as a known set of packages). There is a short hand for this command, `nix-env -qaP php`.

As you can see, there are 3 versions. Now how do we make use of them?

### Install In A Temporary Shell

This is generally how I switch between versions of tools. Nix comes with a built in command called `nix-shell` which allows you to install a package (or packages) and run it just within a shell. To run php5.6:

```
$ nix-shell --packages php56
```

That will download php56 (and it's dependencies), and it will be available within the shell that just launched:

```
[nix-shell:~]$ php --version
PHP 5.6.29 (cli) (built: Dec  8 2016 06:32:02) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
```

If you run `exit` you will be taken out of the `nix-shell` and back to your original shell, run `php` there and you'll see it no longer exists (technically it still exists in the nix store on your system, but that's not something you need to worry about just for this), unless of course you had it installed in the system already.

Now, you can do the same for php7:

```
$ nix-shell --packages php
```

I find this to be the most flexible way of jumping between versions.

### Install In The Nix User Store

Another way is to install in the user store using the `nix-env` command.

```
$ nix-env --install --attr nixpkgs.php56
```

Now `php` 5 should be available, and on your path, no need for a `nix-shell` here:

```
$ php --version
PHP 5.6.29 (cli) (built: Dec  8 2016 06:32:02) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
```

To install `php` 7:

```
$ nix-env --install --attr nixpkgs.php
replacing old ‘php-5.6.29’
installing ‘php-7.0.14’
...
```

As you can see it automatically removes the previous version. To remove manually run `nix-env -e php`. Finally, you can list packages installed in the user store by running `nix-env -qa`.

That barely touches the surface of what nix can do, if this is in anyway helpful I would suggest diving into it a bit more, as, depending on your needs (other tools, php package management etc...), there are likely even better ways to achieve what you want.